# How to send uploaded excel file to C# Post API using Angular 4

Tags: angular, c#-4.0, epplus-4

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', data.target.files[0]);
return this.http.post(url), fd).map().catch();
```

Using AngularJS it's working but for angular 4 when i used the same way it's not working.I am getting disk error while uploading excel file.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In service

`public importMassUpdateExcel(file: FormData, id): Observable<any> {
        const headers = new Headers({
            'Authorization': '',//authorization token 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'// 
        });
        const options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers
        });
        return this.http
            .post(url, file, options)
            .map()
            .catch();
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, which i use to upload files to API via FormData.

In your service file like `upload.service.ts` you need to create function to upload files via POST method. Here is an example for this function:

```
getUploadHeaders() {
    let headers = new Headers({'Accept': 'application/json'});
    headers.delete('Content-Type');
    return headers;
}    

addNewPost(newPost: FormData): Observable<FormData> {
    const endpoint = 'https://yourApiUrl.com'; 
    return this.http
        .post(endpoint, newPost, { headers: this.getUploadHeaders() })
        .catch((e) => this.handleError(e));
}
```

And now you should create upload function in your component, for example `upload.component.ts`. Here is an example for upload function with FormData.

```
fileToUpload: File = null;

constructor(private uploadService: UploadService) { }

handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
  this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
}


saveFileToApi() {
  const saveForm: FormData = new FormData();      
  if (this.fileToUpload) {
    saveForm.append('fileFieldNameOnYourApi', this.fileToUpload, this.fileToUpload.name);
  }

  this.uploadService.addNewPost(saveForm).subscribe(() => {
    console.log('Upload success!');
  }, error => {
    console.log('Upload failed!');
  });
}
```

For uploading an file via FormData you need 3 parameters: propertyName on API endpoint, file and name of this file.
And in your `upload.component.html` you need to have form like this one:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">     
    <label for="fileField">Chose file to upload</label>
    <input type="file"
           id="fileField"
           name="fileField"
           (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
    <button type="submit">Speichern</button>
</form>
```

For more detail of FormData read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) and for more information about FormData.append() read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append).

Comment: Thank You Gregor Doroschenko. Your answer helped to understand but if try this method I am getting  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. this error and disk error so I achieved by recreating authorization and content-type.